Как добавить вложенное контекстное меню через реестр?
Вот недавно начал осваивать редактирование реестра, и добавил парочку пунктов в контекстное меню Windows.
И возник вопрос, как создать вложенное контекстное меню?
Обычные пункты я создаю так:
Win+R -> regedit ->
Компьютер\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell
Далее создаю раздел меню, в нём указываю в параметре (По умолчанию) надпись на пункте меню.
Потом в разделе пункта создаю подраздел command и в его параметре (По умолчанию) указываю путь к файлу программы.
И, если требуется, в корне раздела меню создаю параметр Icon и присваиваю ему значение - путь к иконке пункта.
Выглядит это так:


Это было обычное меню.
А как сделать вложенное?
Например такое:

Если знаете, то подскажите пожалуйста, потому что меню "Открыть с помощью", перестало работать, и я решил создать его альтернативу.
Но для этого мне нужно знать, как создать вложенное подменю.
Заранее спасибо!
